# How to dump/list all kernel symbols with addresses from Linux kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

In a kernel module, how to list all the kernel symbols with their addresses?
The kernel should not be re-compiled.

I know "cat /proc/kallsyms" in an interface, but how to get them directly from kernel data structures, using functions like `kallsyms_lookup_name`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Example

Working module code:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>

static int prsyms_print_symbol(void *data, const char *namebuf,
                               struct module *module, unsigned long address)
{
    pr_info("### %lx\t%s\n", address, namebuf);
    return 0;
}

static int __init prsyms_init(void)
{
    kallsyms_on_each_symbol(prsyms_print_symbol, NULL);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit prsyms_exit(void)
{
}

module_init(prsyms_init);
module_exit(prsyms_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Sam Protsenko");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Module for printing all kernel symbols");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

### Explanation

[kernel/kallsyms.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/kallsyms.c) implements `/proc/kallsyms`. Some of its functions are available for external usage. They are exported via `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL()` macro. Yes, your module should have `GPL` license to use it. Those functions are:

- `kallsyms_lookup_name()`
- `kallsyms_on_each_symbol()`
- `sprint_symbol()`
- `sprint_symbol_no_offset()`

To use those functions, include [`<linux/kallsyms.h>`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kallsyms.h) in your module. It should be mentioned that `CONFIG_KALLSYMS` must be enabled (`=y`) in your kernel configuration.

To print all the symbols you obviously have to use **`kallsyms_on_each_symbol()`** function. The documentation says next about it:

```c
/* Call a function on each kallsyms symbol in the core kernel */
int kallsyms_on_each_symbol(int (*fn)(void *, const char *, struct module *,
                            unsigned long), void *data);
```

where `fn` is your callback function that should be called for each symbol found, and `data` is a pointer to some private data of yours (will be passed as first parameter to your callback function).

Callback function must have next signature:

```c
int fn(void *data, const char *namebuf, struct module *module,
       unsigned long address);
```

This function will be called for each kernel symbol with next parameters:

- `data`: will contain pointer to your private data you passed as last argument to `kallsyms_on_each_symbol()`
- `namebuf`: will contain name of current kernel symbol
- `module`: will always be `NULL`, just ignore that
- `address`: will contain address of current kernel symbol

Return value should always be `0` (on non-zero return value the iteration through symbols will be interrupted).

### Supplemental

Answering the questions in your comment.

> Also, is there a way to output the size of each function?

Yes, you can use `sprint_symbol()` function I mentioned above to do that. It will print symbol information in next format:

```
symbol_name+offset/size [module_name]
```

Example:

```
psmouse_poll+0x0/0x30 [psmouse]
```

Module name part can be omitted if symbol is built-in.

> I tried the module and see the result with "dmesg". But a lot of symbols are missing such as "futex_requeue". The output symbol number is about 10K, while it is 100K when I use "nm vmlinux".

This is most likely because your [printk buffer size](http://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing#Internals_.2F_Changing_the_size_of_the_printk_buffer) is insufficient to store all the output of module above.

Let's improve above module a bit, so it provides symbols information via [miscdevice](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2920). Also let's add function size to the output, as requested. The code as follows:

```c
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/sizes.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>

#define DEVICE_NAME         "prsyms2"
/* 16 MiB is sufficient to store information about approx. 200K symbols */
#define SYMBOLS_BUF_SIZE    SZ_16M

struct symbols {
    char *buf;
    size_t pos;
};

static struct symbols symbols;

/* ---- misc char device definitions ---- */

static ssize_t prsyms2_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count,
                            loff_t *pos)
{
    return simple_read_from_buffer(buf, count, pos, symbols.buf,
                                   symbols.pos);
}

static const struct file_operations prsyms2_fops = {
    .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
    .read   = prsyms2_read,
};

static struct miscdevice prsyms2_misc = {
    .minor  = MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
    .name   = DEVICE_NAME,
    .fops   = &prsyms2_fops,
};

/* ---- module init/exit definitions ---- */

static int prsyms2_store_symbol(void *data, const char *namebuf,
                                struct module *module, unsigned long address)
{
    struct symbols *s = data;
    int count;

    /* Append address of current symbol */
    count = sprintf(s->buf + s->pos, "%lx\t", address);
    s->pos += count;

    /* Append name, offset, size and module name of current symbol */
    count = sprint_symbol(s->buf + s->pos, address);
    s->pos += count;
    s->buf[s->pos++] = '\n';

    if (s->pos >= SYMBOLS_BUF_SIZE)
        return -ENOMEM;

    return 0;
}

static int __init prsyms2_init(void)
{
    int ret;

    ret = misc_register(&prsyms2_misc);
    if (ret)
        return ret;

    symbols.pos = 0;
    symbols.buf = vmalloc(SYMBOLS_BUF_SIZE);
    if (symbols.buf == NULL) {
        ret = -ENOMEM;
        goto err1;
    }

    dev_info(prsyms2_misc.this_device, "Populating symbols buffer...\n");
    ret = kallsyms_on_each_symbol(prsyms2_store_symbol, &symbols);
    if (ret != 0) {
        ret = -EINVAL;
        goto err2;
    }
    symbols.buf[symbols.pos] = '\0';
    dev_info(prsyms2_misc.this_device, "Symbols buffer is ready!\n");

    return 0;

err2:
    vfree(symbols.buf);
err1:
    misc_deregister(&prsyms2_misc);
    return ret;
}

static void __exit prsyms2_exit(void)
{
    vfree(symbols.buf);
    misc_deregister(&prsyms2_misc);
}

module_init(prsyms2_init);
module_exit(prsyms2_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Sam Protsenko");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Module for printing all kernel symbols");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

And here is how to use it:

```
$ sudo insmod prsyms2.ko
$ sudo cat /dev/prsyms2 >symbols.txt
$ wc -l symbols.txt
$ sudo rmmod prsyms2
```

File `symbols.txt` will contain all kernel symbols (both built-in and from loaded modules) in next format:

```
ffffffffc01dc0d0    psmouse_poll+0x0/0x30 [psmouse]
```

> It seems that I can use `kallsyms_lookup_name()` to find the address of the function, can then use a function pointer to call the function?

Yes, you can. If I recall correctly, it's called [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29). Below is an example how to do so:

```c
    typedef int (*custom_print)(const char *fmt, ...);

    custom_print my_print;

    my_print = (custom_print)kallsyms_lookup_name("printk");
    if (my_print == 0) {
        pr_err("Unable to find printk\n");
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    my_print(KERN_INFO "### printk found!\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried the module and see the result with "dmesg". But a lot of symbols are missing such as "futex_requeue". The output symbol number is about 10K, while it is 100K when I use "nm vmlinux". Also, is there a way to output the size of each function?

Comment: @WindChaser Your questions were addressed in **Supplemental** section in my answer.

Comment: It seems that kallsyms_lookup(addr, &size, NULL, NULL, NULL) can get the   size from symbol address.

Comment: However, in the kernel module, kallsyms_lookup() cannot be used. Any approach to put the size into a variable, instead of printing everything out?

Comment: @WindChaser You are right, `kallsyms_lookup()` not exported, so it can't be used from module. As for dedicated function for symbol size: no, there is no such function exported. If your goal is only educational -- feel free to develop function that parses `sprint_symbol()` output and returns symbol size as `unsigned long`. If this task is from real work -- I'd encourage you to make a patch that exports the function you need, and to send this patch to corresponding kernel mailing lists for review. If you specify why it's needed (in commit message) -- it can be merged in mainline kernel.

Comment: @WindChaser Actually I wonder, why do you need to do all that stuff? Is it some educational investigation, or you really need this for some reason? Just curious.

Comment: It's part of an R&D project in the company.

Comment: @WindChaser I see. So all you can do right now is write a temporary hack, parsing the result of `sprint_symbol()`. To avoid this issue in future -- make a patch to `kernel/kallsyms.c` / `include/linux/kallsyms.h` and send it to upstream. It sound reasonable to have API for getting symbol size, so I guess it most likely will be pulled in. If you need help with any of those -- just let me know, or ask it as a new question.

Comment: It seems that I can use `kallsyms_lookup_name()` to find the address of the function, can then use a function pointer to call the function.

Comment: @WindChaser I added the answer to your question to **Supplemental** section.

Comment: Looks like this answer will need quite the revision for Linux 5.7: https://lwn.net/Articles/813350/

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yeah, so in short: in new kernels just embrace the EXPORT_SYMBOL() and stop doing that reflection stuff. For debugging reasons one can just revert (locally) those patches you pointed out.