# How can I enable the kernel module's address symbol?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, kernel-module

I wrote a simple kernel module file, after I `insmod` it, I want to find it's address symbol,so I execute:

```
root@hmd8890:/ # cat /proc/modules                                             
hellotest 878 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000 (O)
```

or:

```
root@hmd8890:/ # cat /sys/module/hellotest/sections/.init.text             
0x0000000000000000
```

but the address symbol are all `0x0000000000000000`, I think it should be as:

```
[root@vexpress mnt]# cat /proc/modules 
hellotest 797 0 - Live 0xbf000000 (O)
```

`0xbf000000` is ok for me.

How can I find the right symbol table? Do I miss the `kernelconfig` file select options? Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: [Linux kernel exported symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10070861/608639), [How to dump/list all kernel symbols with addresses from Linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37978245/608639) and [The Kernel Newbie Corner: Kernel Symbols: What's Available to Your Module, What Isn't](https://www.linux.com/learn/kernel-newbie-corner-kernel-symbols-whats-available-your-module-what-isnt)

Comment: It looks like you have a 64bit ARM kernel?  Do you have symbols in the module with `nm`?  You should be building as described in [kbuild/modules.txt](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt).  If you build a different way, getting this working will depend on the steps you take.